# Vb.net project running on Windows 7 but not XP

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

I have recently created a VB.Net Windows Form app on my windows 7 pc and am having issues with it randomly crashing on an XP machine. There doesn't seem to be much of a patter either. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

### Details

Tried both building the project and compiling an install with all references.
Platform set for Active (x86)
Xp machine has all .dlls registered and .Net 4.0 framework
Program runs and crashes at random spots
Alot of different connections to databases
Cannot step through code on Xp as no visual studio available but no errors or exceptions on Win7 machine when running or stepping through code.

Any help would be great if someone has encountered a similar problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try remote debugging from visual studio or simply just running a debug version of the software and using logging. But there isn't enough information here to help

Comment: What's the error message? How you looked at event viewer?

Comment: the_lotus, you're a life saver. That is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Answer came from the_Lotus

What's the error message? How you looked at event viewer? –  the_lotus

After opening eventviewer and looking at the details it appears there was a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

Thanks again the_Lotus